# How to link from Cordova app to Waze deep linking?

Tags: cordova, waze

I am trying to make a link from my cordova app to directly open the Waze app, but this opens something like "browserly" waze, instead of the real app. This is what I have tried:

```
<a href="https://www.waze.com/he/livemap?ll=40.75889500%2C-73.98513100&navigate=yes&zoom=17" external>
 Open waze
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually mentioned in [docs](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/).
`https://www.waze.com/ul` is the base URL for deeplinks.
So this should work.

```
<a href="https://www.waze.com/ul/livemap?ll=40.75889500%2C-73.98513100&navigate=yes&zoom=17" external>
 Open waze
</a>
```